# associating a topic attribute to a bookmark

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a new Bookmark so its associated with a Topic. Everytime I try and do so, my `topic_id is nil`.

Here is my bookmark_controller's create method:

```
def create
   @bookmark = Bookmark.new(params[:bookmark].permit!)
   #@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
   @bookmark.topic_id = @topic_id
   @bookmark.user = current_user
   authorize @bookmark

if @bookmark.save
  flash[:notice] = "Bookmark was saved."
  redirect_to [@topic, @bookmark]
else
  flash[:error] = "There was an error, try it again."
  render :new
end
end
```

Bookmark.rb

```
    class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base

     belongs_to :topic
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
     end
```

Comment: Where did you assign a value to `@topic_id`?

Comment: Is the reader expected to know something about the `Bookmark` class? (There's only a Ruby tag.)

Comment: One of two things: 1) use `params[:topic_id]` instead of `@topic_id`, or 2) uncomment your commented line, and use `@topic.id` instead of `@topic_id`. Either way, `@topic_id` never had a value assigned to it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland is the newbie expected to know exaclty what to put? @Jon, I unnested Bookmarks from topics, so `params[:topic_id] ` doesn't  work.

Comment: I don't know Rails and therefore didn't recognize `Bookmark`, though I suspected it had something to do with Rails. Tags should be accurate.  Some readers only look at questions with Rails' tags, so they would have missed yours; others don't want to see questions with Rails' tags, so you'd be wasting their time. When you have time, have a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, my only two tags are `ruby-on-rails` and `ruby`, which is exactly what this problem involves.

Comment: Those two tags are fine, but I made my initial comment when there was only a Ruby tag, and my second comment was intended to explain why tags need to be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BartDangus,

You need to pass the Topic ID in the params. Otherwise, there is no way to know which topic the Bookmark is to be associated. It makes the most sense to nest Bookmark under Topic so that the Topic ID is always sent. I read in the comments that you unnested Bookmark from Topic; can you elaborate on why?

If you nest Bookmark, then changing `@bookmark.topic_id = @topic_id` to `@bookmark.topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])` will work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I ended up nesting the bookmarks under the topics. It made it a lot easier for me to work through. I was advised against nesting, but it makes the most sense to me on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the @topic_id variable. When not defined, variables return nil.

I would suggest changing this:

```
#@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
@bookmark.topic_id = @topic_id
```

to this:

```
@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
@bookmark.topic = @topic
```

or this:

```
#@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
@bookmark.topic_id = params[:topic_id]
```

Comment: `@bookmark.topic_id = @topic_id` still returns nil. Finding the topic_id doing `@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])` returns `Couldn't find Topic with 'id'=` @bacrossland

Comment: @BartDangus if `topic_id` is nil then you need to look at the view that is calling the `create` action. You need to send the `topic_id` from that view. This can be sent through a nested url or a hidden_field.